# Twig extension Symfony5 : create a NavBar with a SearchBar for every Controller

Tags: symfony, twig, navbar, searchbar

I'm trying to generate a twig extension (or if it can be something else) that **could avoid me repeating** my navigation bar and search bar code **onto every controller**. I've been searching tutorials for this scenario for a long time, and have always failed (tried making a service, now a twig extension... I can't seem to figure it out even though it must be a very common issue/thing to do)

1. One of my first issue is that I cannot use the `->createForm` method since I am not in a Controller (when I'm trying to make a Twig Extension) but I do need it to generate my SearchBar.

Should I inject a service to deal with that ? I'm a bit lost.

2. I use dynamic dropdowns (loaded from database) which is why I call the $marqueRepository and $categoryRepository.

Here is what my MainController looks like (and what I currently copy to every other controller to make my navigation work) :

```
class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_home")
     */
    public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, MarqueRepository $marqueRepository, Request $request)
    {
        $products = $productRepository->findBy(['status' => 1]);
        $marques = $marqueRepository->findAll();
        $categories = $categoryRepository->findAll();

        $formSearch = $this->createForm(SearchForm::class);
        $searchRequest = $formSearch->handleRequest($request);  // je demande au formulaire de traiter la requête

        //dump($searchRequest->get('search')->getData());  //je test ma requête et vérifie que je récupère bien mes éléments recherchés
        
        if($formSearch->isSubmitted() && $formSearch->isValid()){
            $products = $productRepository->findSearch($searchRequest->get('search')->getData()
        );
        }

        $productsMain = $productRepository->findTopEight();

        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', [
            'formSearch' => $formSearch->createView(),
            'productsMain' => $productsMain,
            'products' => $products,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'marques' => $marques,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my _navbar.html.twig partial :

```
<div class="top-header" id="#top">
    <div class="sign">
        <h1 class="top-header_title">Online~Shop</h1>
        <h3 class="top-header_main-title">Site en construction (MAJ le 12/02/2021)</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="left-container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_home') }}">Accueil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('products_liste') }}">Produits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Catégories
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                {% for c in categories %}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('categories_details', {'id' : c.id} ) }}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Marques
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                {% for m in marques %}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ m.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            {{ form_start(formSearch, {attr: {class: 'search_form'}}) }}
            {{ form_row(formSearch.search, {attr: {class: 'filter-search_input'}}) }}  <!-- on personnalise le design du formulaire 'search' étant la variable de la barre de recherche -->
            {{ form_end(formSearch) }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right-container">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_user') }}"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is what it looks like visually :[image: The visual render of my navbar]

Comment: Using an [embedded controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-embed-controllers) is one approach.  It might look a bit overwhelming at first but work through the example.  And off-topic but if you are going to do stuff with Symfony then take the time to work through the service examples as well.

Comment: @Cerad I have made an embedded controller, and it does render my navbar on every page using the symfony documentation. 
I still have an issue, it's that my navbarController (the embedded controller) won't treat the request when I test my search bar, whereas before it used to deal with it when I had it in every controller. Any idea of how to help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is simply to render a navigation bar with variables, the embedded controller is really easy to set up, and works perfectly fine for me (see code below).
[credits to @Cerad  - [Embedded Controllers -Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-embed-controllers) ]

My embedded controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\MarqueRepository;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class NavBarController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/navbar", name="navbar")
     */
    public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, MarqueRepository $marqueRepository)
    {
        $products = $productRepository->findBy(['status' => 1]);
        $marques = $marqueRepository->findAll();
        $categories = $categoryRepository->findAll();
   
        $productsMain = $productRepository->findTopEight();

        return $this->render('navbar/_navbar.html.twig', [
            'productsMain' => $productsMain,
            'products' => $products,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'marques' => $marques,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then inside my `base.html.twig` :

```
{% block nav %}
    {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\NavBarController::index')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Asking another question with an answer is generally not a good idea.  Embedded controllers actually generate sub-requests which do not have the same info as the original master request.  Use [RequestStack::getMasterRequest()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html).

Comment: Hi again @Cerad, thank you for following up and helping me out. I thought I would share a first answer with the community, if people want a simple Embedded Controller example (but I am going to improve that answer by taking out some code that deals with the request, just for that first answer). As soon as I have got an anwser for the getMasterRequest I will also post an answer, no ?
I'm a bit new to this community, so any adivse is welcomed :)

Comment: @Cerad Hello, I'm having trouble with the requestStack. It seems to be configured for Services, and I made an embedded controller. If I try converting my embedded controller into a service, I lose the possibility to ->createForm() ... I'm a bit lost. 

When i try the RequestStack I have no errors but my request is "null" when i dump it.

Comment: In your index method, replace Request with RequestStack and go from there.

Comment: You mean, in the MainController (for example) or in the NavBarController (embedded controller) for the replacement of the Request with RequestStack ?

QUestion is, do I need to deal with the Request/RequestStack in every Controller, or is the embedded controller going to deal with that by itself ?

Thank you @Cerad